# Why typescript complains object's key is undefined even if the previous command sets a value to that key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

```
type MaybeThereIsAValue = {
  [p: string]: string | undefined
}

...

let bar: MaybeThereIsAValue = {};
const key = "carpe";
bar[key] = "diem";

const why = bar[key];
// why is string | undefined
```

Why is `why` `string | undefined` since I am literally assigning a value to `bar[key]` in the previous line ?

How can I avoid it ?

[image]

Check example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAKgCwgJwgSQM4CCAanADYCu0AvFAN4CwAUFFANpgBcUewmAlgDsA5gF0uPfsKgAfKOQEATCADNBEBUwC%20TJqQjAoiOJi7wkqDNnzEylKDVqaA3EwDGAewE8oAawgh7KAAiV2NIIJdGI0xWPxARQKCFPggAWwidRjdPbwB3NACaaNj-EUigA)

Comment: Why I can't get the type `string | undefined`, my `why` is type of 'string'

Comment: @zixiCat Don't know. When I hover my mouse over the why, my IDE says it's string | undefined, check the attached image I just uploaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got why it would get that.

That is because [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) of tsconfig is set to be `true`, which default is false,

and `const key = 'carpe'` is only executed after the TS is compiled into JS, so TS doesn't know which key it is.

---

*strictNullChecks: When type checking, take into account null and undefined.*

---

So if you want to solve that, my two solutions are:

**1. set the `strictNullChecks` of `tsconfig` to be `false`**

**2. Use `!`** [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

```
const why = bar[key]!;
```

---

Let's think about this situation:

```
let key = 'carpe';
bar[key] = 'diem';
// the next line would only be executed after the TS is compiled into JS.
key = 'test';  
// that is to say TS does not know the key is 'test' or 'carpe'
// so `why` is type of string or undefined

const why = bar[key];
```

If you set `strictNullChecks` to be false, `why` will always be type of string

Comment: I get it to work with the ```!``` at the end but could you elaborate more ? I mean why the distinction between ```null``` and ```undefined``` would cause such an issue since I explicitly declare it as ```string | undefined``` and not ```string | null | undefined``` ?

Comment: there no diff between them, `strictNullChecks` just let it consider the type of this object if contains null or undefined,  if you set 
____________________________________________________________________________________
`type MaybeThereIsAValue = {
  [p: string]: string | undefined | null;
};`
____________________________________________________________________________________
 perhaps `why` is type of `string | undefined | null`